# Passing JWTs securely back to the mobile app frontend after signing in with Google OAuth2

Tags: design, authentication, oauth2

I have a server(API) written in Flask and a client(mobile app) written in React Native. The application allows for logging in with either email/password OR with Google. The Google authentication flow works as such:

1. User presses on the `Sign in with Google` button;
2. Frontend sends the user to the API endpoint /api/google/authorize, which in turn redirects the user to the Google login page where he has to log in and authorize our app to access his account information;
3. User successfully logged in on the Google page and is now redirected back to our API via the `/api/google/callback` endpoint;
4. The callback endpoint exchanges the authorization code sent by Google with an access token and ID token pair. Additionally the user is created if they did not exist up until now.
5. Now I have to pass this ID token (and a refresh token ultimately) back to the frontend so that further requests made to the API are authenticated/authorized.

The part that I'm having issues with is the last one, where I have to send the tokens back to the frontend in a secure manner. I've read online about what options are there and these are the ones that I kind of considered:

1. `Authorization Code` - This would consist of creating a temporary code which then would be exchanged for a token pair in another endpoint, the code would be sent in the query parameters of the redirect back to the app. Unfortunately I don't like the fact that this feels like a duplicate of the OAuth process since during the authentication process I'm using two authorization codes (one from Google and then one generated by my API). Additionally I would have to implement security measures so that not just anyone could use the authorization code issued by my API, but only the frontend/current user.
2. `Custom URI Scheme/Deep Linking` - This would consist of having a custom URI scheme like `myapp://` instead of `https://` and then I would send the tokens as query parameters to the frontend. I tend to go towards this idea more because it feels like its both safe, flexible and does not add a lot of complexity/code. It's just the fact that the frontend would have to add code for listening for this custom URI. Maybe there are downsides to doing it this way that I don't know of?

I would really appreciate if you could tell me if there are other options that I might consider? This is the first time that I'm designing the authentication flow for a mobile app (previously I've only worked on web applications).

Thanks in advance!